How to add a custom module to my solution with VoloAbp.Studio.Cli
I have a custom module, but don't know how to add that module to my solution.
I want to create new modules with Volo.Abo.Studio.Cli and add them to my solution!
I want to create new modules with Volo.Abo.Studio.Cli and add them to my solution!
I want to create new modules with Volo.Abo.Studio.Cli and add them to my solution!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
